# ¿Cómo realizar una llamada AJAX sin bibliotecas?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Con jQuery y otras bibliotecas JavaScript se pueden realizar llamadas AJAX de una manera sencilla utilizandoa algo como esto:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "miURl",
   method: "GET",
   data: "var1=valor1&var2=valor2",
   success: function(d) {
      // código aquí
   }
});
```

El problema es que en algunos proyectos me he encontrado con que añadía bibliotecas JavaScript exclusivamente para usar la función AJAX y para llamadas bastante básicas (principalmente GETs en los que no me importaba el error, sólo el resultado, si alguno)... y no tiene mucho sentido agregar un fichero de 85-300KB sólo para eso.

¿Cómo sería una función básica en JavaScript que tomase como parámetro una URL, una función que hará de `success` (no me importa el `error`) y opcionalmente el método (GET o POST), una lista de variables, y que funcionase de manera "similar" a como lo hace [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

La respuesta debe ser independiente del servidor en el que se ejecute y si eso no es posible entonces debe funcionar para Apache.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> La respuesta debe ser independiente del servidor en el que se ejecute
>   y si eso no es posible entonces debe funcionar para Apache.

Uses la librería que uses, todo se transforma al mismo código (o parecido, pero usando los mismos estándares) y el servidor interpretará la misma petición.

[image]

*Fuente: [¿Cómo funciona AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work).*

De la parte **naranja** te encargas tú, el resto está predefinido en los servidores.

---

Voy a dividir mi respuesta en 2 líneas de tiempo ;)

### Vieja escuela

Esta forma es la clásica y *prácticamente* multi-navegador, además de ser la estándar por muchos años. La clase que nos provee esto es la interface [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Basta con crear un objeto `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Después, debemos especificar por medio del método `open` los siguientes parámetros:

- Método de la petición
- URL del recurso
- Bandera para indicar si debe ser asíncrona (por defecto true)

Siguiendo con el ejemplo, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
xhr.open('GET', '//api.awesomemag.com/magazines');
```

Con esto ya establecemos los parámetro a la petición. Nos resta **asociar una función** para las *fases de la petición* del ciclo de vida de la petición.

```
xhr.onload = function() {
  if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
    // respuesta lista para procesar
  }
}
```

> Una petición AJAX tiene un ciclo de vida durante su carga

Éstos son:

- 0: Petición aún no inicializada
- 1: Conexión establecida con el servidor
- 2: Petición enviada
- 3: Proceso de la petición
- 4: Respuesta lista

Es por ésta razón que debemos actuar en la fase `4`, cuando la respuesta esté lista para nosotros (salvo casos extraordinarios, como siempre, puede actuarse en otra(s) fase(s)):

```
if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
  // respuesta lista para procesar
}
```

Finalmente, enviamos la petición:

```
xhr.send();
```

---

#### Anexo: Envío de datos por POST

No es novedad que en una petición `GET`, no podemos enviar datos en el cuerpo de la petición; lo que hacen librerías como jQuery es leer el objetos que le pasamos a `data` y agruparlos por `?clave=valor` para finalmente anexarlos a la URL.

Por el método `POST` **sí** se puede enviar datos, para lo cual disponemos de algunas opciones que menciono a continuación.

**FormData**

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) es una interface que nos permite simular un `submit` de formulario enviando los datos que les añadamos como `clave/valor`, de hecho, ésta interface usa el mime `multipart/form-data`.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("title", "Be careful! NSA spy through smartphones backdoors!");
data.append("date", new Date().getTime());
xhr.send(data);
```

**Forma manual**

Esta forma es igual que con `FormData`, la diferencia es que acá lo haces de forma manual como si se tratase de parámetros get:

```
xhr.send('title=Be careful! NSA spy through smartphones backdoors!&date=' + new Date().getTime());
```

**JSON**

Para enviar objetos a través de `XMLHttpRequest` basta con hacer uso de `JSON.stringify` para serializar ese objeto:

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    title: 'Be careful! NSA spy through smartphones backdoors!',
    date: new Date().getTime()
}));
```

---

### Nueva escuela

Recientemente ha sido liberada una nueva API basada en `Promesas`, llamada [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). De alguna manera, hace el código más limpio.

**GET**

Para realizar una petición `GET`, basta con pasar la `URL` del recurso y hacer uso de `then` y `catch` para el éxito y error respectivamente.

```
fetch('//api.awesomemag.com/magazines')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(magazines => console.log(magazines))
  .catch(err => console.log('Algo salió mal'));
```

Alternativamente, si esperamos recibir un `JSON` debemos incluir el header correspondiente:

```
fetch('//api.awesomemag.com/magazines', {
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(magazines => console.log(magazines))
  .catch(err => console.log('Algo salió mal'));
```

Pero hay otra razón por la cual ésta alternativa será muy utilizada y tiene que ver con una **próxima** característica de EcmaScript, se trata de [Async/Await](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait).

> ¿Cuál es la asociación entre **Fetch** y **Async/Await**?

Es muy simple. `Async/Await` hará posible **esperar** a que termine un procedimiento asíncrono, dándonos en ocasiones **donde necesitemos** éste comportamiento, una clara ventaja y naturalidad al programador backend generalmente procedural. Lo podemos entender mejor con un ejemplo:

```
function async getMagazines() {
  return fetch('//api.awesomemag.com/magazines');
}

// flujo natural
const magazines = await (getMagazines()).json();
// no necesitamos de promesas ni callbacks!
```

> Algunas personas están en contra de esta nueva característica, argumentando que *matan* la naturaleza asíncrona de JavaScript.

---

### Conclusiones

> Propuestas en Stage 3+ prácticamente están aseguradas; en Stage 2 tienen una alta probabilidad de ser incluídas.

Actualmente disponemos de transpiladores que nos permiten *usar* EcmaScript 6,7 y 8 así como futuras inclusiones en el lenguaje sin perder compatibilidad entre navegadores. Una de las más famosas es [Babel](https://babel.io) que transpila código moderno a EcmaScript 5 (JavaScript del 2009).

Comment: ¡Gracias!, acabo de solucionar mi problema a la vieja usanza (escuela). Gracias por la explicación tan detallada, todo un lujo.

Answer (score 10):

## 1. Código

Armé esta función que sigue exactamente la misma sintaxis de [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) y sólo hay que incluirla en el código para utilizarla. Está escrita para ser compatible tambén con navegadores más viejos.

```js
function ajax(url, opciones){
    //parametros pasados
    opciones = opciones || {};
    if (typeof url === "object" && url !== null) {
        opciones = url; //url como param o como propiedad
        url = opciones.url;
    }
    url = url || "";
    opciones.method = opciones.method || opciones.type || "GET";
    opciones.method = opciones.method.toUpperCase();

    function crearObjetoXMLHttp() {
        //Crear el objeto para el HTTP request
        if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined")
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        else { //para IE6-
            const XMLHttpVersions = [
                    "MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0",
                    "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0",
                    "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
                    "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",
                    "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
                    "Microsoft.XmlHttp"
                ];
            const XMLHttpVersionsLength = XMLHttpVersions.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < XMLHttpVersionsLength; i++) {
                try {
                    return new ActiveXObject(XMLHttpVersions[i]);
                } catch (e) { }
            }

            throw new ReferenceError("No se puede crear una instancia para el objeto XMLHttpRequest");
        }
    }
    var http_request;
    if (typeof opciones.xhr === 'function')
        http_request = opciones.xhr()
    else
        http_request = crearObjetoXMLHttp();

    //asignamos una función que se llamara (asincronicamente) 
    //  cuando cambie el estado de la petición
    function respuestaAJAX() {
        if (http_request.readyState == (XMLHttpRequest.DONE || 4)) { // 4 significa que terminó
            var status;
            if (http_request.status >= 200 && http_request.status < 300 || http_request.status == 304) { //2xx Success
                //aca leemos la respuesta (lel recurso devuelto)
                // y se llama al callback definido por el usuario
                status = "success";
                statusAJAX(http_request, status);
                if (typeof opciones.success === "function") {
                    var response;
                    try {
                        if (opciones.dataType == "json") { //si se espera un json
                            response = JSON.parse(http_request.response);
                            response.__proto__.toString = function(){ return JSON.stringify(this) };
                        } else if (opciones.dataType == "xml") { //si se espera un xml
                            response = http_request.responseXML;
                            response.__proto__.toString = function(){ return this.innerHTML };
                        } else { //si se espera texto
                            response = http_request.response;
                        }
                        // Callback a success
                        opciones.success(response);
                        completoAJAX(http_request, status);
                    } catch (err) { //error al interpretar json o xml
                        console.error(err);
                        if (typeof opciones.error === "function") {
                            status = "parseerror";
                            errorAJAX(http_request, status);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (http_request.responseURL !== "") {  //Otra respuesta (ej: 500 Internal Server Error)
                status = "error";
                statusAJAX(http_request, status);
                //lanzar error
                errorAJAX(http_request, status);
            }
        }
    }
    addEvent(http_request, "readystatechange", respuestaAJAX);


    function errorAJAX(http_request, status) {
        //llamamos al callback the "error" si se especifico
        status = status || "error";
        if (typeof opciones.error !== "undefined") {
            var statusText = (http_request.statusText  || "").replace(/^\d+ /,"");
            if (typeof opciones.error === "function")
                opciones.error = [ opciones.error ];
            var errorLength = opciones.error.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < errorLength; i++) {
                opciones.error[i](http_request, status, statusText);
            }
        }
        completoAJAX(http_request, status);
    }

    function statusAJAX(http_request, status) {
        //si se definio por ej, statusCode: { 500: function(){ /* */ } }
        if (typeof opciones.statusCode === "object" && typeof opciones.statusCode[http_request.status] === "function")
            opciones.statusCode[http_request.status](http_request, status, (http_request.statusText.replace(/^\d+ /,"")  || ""));
    }

    function completoAJAX(http_request, status) {
        //llamamos al callback the "complete" si se especifico
        if (typeof opciones.complete !== "undefined") {
            if (typeof opciones.complete === "function")
                opciones.complete = [ opciones.complete ];
            var completeLength = opciones.complete.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < completeLength; i++) {
                opciones.complete[i](http_request, status);
            }
        }
    }

    //handlers para los errores
    const ajaxErrorEvents = ["abort", "error", "timeout"];
    const ajaxErrorEventsLength = ajaxErrorEvents.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < ajaxErrorEventsLength; i++) {
        const ajaxErrorEvent = ajaxErrorEvents[i];
        addEvent(http_request, ajaxErrorEvent, function() {
            errorAJAX(http_request, ajaxErrorEvent);
        });
    }

    function addEvent(elemento, evento, callback, arg) {
        if (elemento.addEventListener) { //addEventListener
            elemento.addEventListener(evento, callback, (arg || false));
        } else if (elemento.attachEvent) { //attachEvent para IE
            elemento.attachEvent("on" + evento, callback);
        } else {
            elemento[ "on" + evento ] = callback;
        }
    }

    //timeout
    if (typeof opciones.timeout !== "undefined")
        http_request.timeout = opciones.timeout;

    //preparamos los datos a enviar
    var data = null;
    if (typeof opciones.data !== "undefined" && (opciones.data !== null || opciones.cache === false)) {
        if (opciones.processData === false) {
            data = opciones.data;
        } else if (typeof opciones.data === "string") {
            data = encodeURI(opciones.data.replace(/^\?/,""));
        } else if (typeof opciones.data === "object") {
            var dataArr = [];
            for (var key in opciones.data) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(opciones.data, key)) {
                    dataArr[dataArr.length] = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" 
                                            + encodeURIComponent(typeof opciones.data[key] === "string" 
                                                                 ? opciones.data[key]
                                                                 : JSON.stringify(opciones.data[key]));
                }
            }
            data = dataArr.join("&");
        }
        //Si es GET, data va en el query del uri
        if (opciones.method == "GET") {
            if (opciones.cache === false) //no usar cache
                data += (data?"?":"") + "_=" + (Date.now?Date.now():new Date().getTime());
            url += "?" + data;
            data = null;
        }
    }

    //hacemos el request
    http_request.open(opciones.method, url, true, opciones.username, opciones.password);
    //forms
    if (opciones.method == "POST" || opciones.method == "PUT")
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //completamos encabezados
    for (var encabezado in opciones.headers) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(opciones.headers, encabezado))
            http_request.setRequestHeader(encabezado.replace(/(?:^([a-z])|([a-z]))([a-z0-9_]*)([A-Z]+)/g,
                                                             function(m,p1,p2,p3,p4){return (p1?p1.toUpperCase():p2)+p3+"-"+p4}), 
                                          opciones.headers[encabezado]);
    }
    //dataType y contentType
    if (opciones.dataType == "xml") {
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
    } else if (opciones.dataType == "json") {
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    }
    if (typeof opciones.contentType !== "undefined") { //Content-Type x usuario
        http_request.overrideMimeType(opciones.contentType);
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", opciones.contentType);
    }
    //beforeSend
    if (typeof opciones.beforeSend === "function") {
        if (opciones.beforeSend(http_request, opciones) === false) {
            http_request.abort();
            return false;
        }
    }
    //send
    http_request.send(data);
    return true;
}
```

#### Opciones implementadas

`beforeSend`, `cache`, `complete`, `contentType`, `data` <sub>(sólo objetos y arrays)</sub>, `dataType` <sub>(sólo xml y json)</sub>, `error`, `headers`, `method`, `mimeType`, `password`, `processData`, `statusCode`, `success`, `timeout`, `type`, `url`, `username`, `xhr`.

Para ver la forma de usarlos, se puede leer la documentación de [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

#### Ejemplos de uso

- Obtener el contenido de una url.

  ```js
  ajax({
      url: "miURL",
      method: "GET",
      data: "var1=valor1&var2=valor2",
      contentType: "text/plain",
      success: function(d) {
          console.log(d);
      }
  });
  ```
- Enviar encabezados, obtener un XML y aplicarle métodos de DOM, o evaluar el error.

  ```js
  ajax({
      url: "nota.xml",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "xml",
      headers: {
          AcceptLanguage: "es-AR; q=1.0, es; q=0.9, en; 0.5, pt; 0.2",
          CacheControl: "no-cache"
      },
      success: function(d) {
          console.log(d.querySelectorAll("*"));
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.warn("ERROR", xhr, status, error);
      }
  });
  ```
- Enviar parámetros por POST y recibir un JSON

  ```js
  ajax({
      url: "archivo.json",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
          var1: "valor1",
          var2: "valor2"
      },
      success: function(d) {
          console.log(d.parametro[2]);
      },
      complete: function(xhr, status) {
          console.info("Se finalizo la peticion por AJAX. Status:", status);
      }
  });
  ```

---

## 2. Descripción de cómo funciona

#### 2.a. Pasos básicos

Veamos los pasos esenciales de la solicitud AJAX (lo que importa de todo el código).

1. Instanciamos `XmlHttp`

   ```js
   var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ```

   En realidad se recibe como resultado de la función `crearObjetoXMLHttp()`.

   *Esta función está para la compatibilidad con IE. Si no es compatible con `XMLHttpRequest`, genera el objeto ActiveX `MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0` (o una versión previa que sí sea compatible).*

2. Registramos el evento `onreadystatechange` para gestionarlo.

   ```js
   http_request.addEventListener('readystatechange', respuestaAJAX);
   ```

   Para cada cambio en el estado de la petición AJAX, se llamará a la función `respuestaAJAX()`.

   *Nuevamente, definimos una función para lidiar con versiones previas de IE, llamando a `addEvent()` para que, si no es compatible con `addEventListener`, use `attachEvent` o, en su defecto, lo asigne directamente a `.onreadystatechange`.*

3. Inicializamos la petición AJAX y lo enviamos.

   ```js
   http_request.open(opciones.method, url);
   http_request.send(data);
   ```

   Donde se pasa `"POST"` o `"GET"` dentro del parámetro `opciones.method`. Y `data` puede contener el cuerpo de la petición o no (discutido más abajo).

4. Recibimos la respuesta y se dispara la función `respuestaAJAX()` (registrada en el punto **2**).

   La petición se realiza de forma asíncronica, y la función `ajax()` termina de ejecutarse antes de recibir la respuesta. Sin embargo, al recibir cambios en el estado de la petición, el evento `readystatechange` va cambiando y llamando a la función que asignamos.

   ```js
   function respuestaAJAX() {
   ```

   De todos los cambios de estado, únicamente nos interesa el último, cuando la petición terminó:

   ```js
       if (http_request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
   ```

   Y, si se obtuvo una respuesta satisfactoria, ejecutamos la función definida por el usuario (pasada como *callback*).

   ```js
           if (http_request.status >= 200 && http_request.status < 300 
               || http_request.status == 304) {

               opciones.success(response);
           }
   ```

Esto es todo lo que se necesita para una petición AJAX. El resto del código se encarga exclusivamente de modificar algunos parámetros enviados o recibidos, y de disparar eventos en caso de error.

#### 2.b Envío de datos

Recién vimos que se podían enviar o no datos en `http_request.send(data);`. Éstos son pasados como parámetro dentro de las opciones como string:

```js
ajax({
    url:  "pagina.php",
    data: "var1=valor1&var2=valor2"
});
```

o como un objeto:

```js
ajax({
    url:  "pagina.php",
    data: {
        var1: "valor1",
        var2: "valor2"
    }
});
```

Si se pasan como string, se codifica con [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURI) y lo asignamos:

```js
if (typeof opciones.data === "string") {
    data = encodeURI(opciones.data);
}
```

Y si se pasan como objeto, se codifica cada clave y valor con [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent):

```js
else if (typeof opciones.data === "object") {
    var dataArr = [];
    for (var key in opciones.data) {
        dataArr[dataArr.length] = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(opciones.data[key]);
    }
    data = dataArr.join("&");
}
```

Por último, si estamos realizando una petición por `POST`, los datos se envían directamente en el cuerpo de la petición, en la forma `var1=valor1&var2=valor2` y se configura el encabezado de `Content-Type`:

```js
http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Pero si es una petición por `GET`, los datos se agregan directamente en la URL, quedando por ejemplo `pagina.php?var1=valor1&var2=valor2`.

```js
if (opciones.method == "GET") {
    url += "?" + data;
    data = null;
}
```

#### 2.c Análisis de la respuesta

A la función se le puede pasar el parámetro `dataType` con el valor `"json"` o `"xml"` para especificar el tipo de datos recibido en la solicitud, haciendo que se procese la respuesta con [`json.PARSE()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) o directamente obteniendo el [`XMLHttpRequest.responseXML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML).

```js
if (opciones.dataType == "json") { //si se espera un json
    response = JSON.parse(http_request.response);
    response.__proto__.toString = function(){ return JSON.stringify(this) };
} else if (opciones.dataType == "xml") { //si se espera un xml
    response = http_request.responseXML;
    response.__proto__.toString = function(){ return this.innerHTML };
}
```

Por otro lado, si `http_request.status` no devuelve un valor en el rango de 200 a 299 (o 304), significa que el servidor respondió con un error (por ejemplo, "404 Not Found"). En ese caso, si se le pasó una función (o varias) como parámetro de `error`, se ejecuta como callback.

```js
if (typeof opciones.error !== "undefined") {
    var statusText = (http_request.statusText  || "").replace(/^\d+ /,"");
    if (typeof opciones.error === "function")
        opciones.error = [ opciones.error ];
    var errorLength = opciones.error.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < errorLength; i++) {
        opciones.error[i](http_request, status, statusText);
    }
}
```

---

## 3. Alternativa más moderna

Otra opción es utilizar [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch)[image: experimental], mucho más práctica y sencilla de utilizar. Esta opción está muy bien descripta [en la respuesta de MitsuG](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/25844/127). Sin embargo, aún [no es compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch#Browser_compatibility) con IE ni Safari.

Answer (score 2):

Al día de esta respuesta la API *Fetch* esta soportada por los navegadores en su gran mayoría como lo demuestra la imagen siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> [Soporte de Fetch](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)

**EJEMPLO PETICIÓN GET**

Tienes una URL almacenada dentro de una variable de este modo

```
const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`
```

Si hacemos lo siguiente

```
const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`


fetch(url)
   .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Obtenemos como resultado lo siguiente

> [object Response] { arrayBuffer: function arrayBuffer() { [native
>   code] }, blob: function blob() { [native code] }, body: [object
>   ReadableStream] { ... }, bodyUsed: false, clone: function clone() {
>   [native code] }, formData: function formData() { [native code] },
>   headers: [object Headers] { append: function append() { [native code]
>   }, delete: function delete() { [native code] }, entries: function
>   entries() { [native code] }, forEach: function forEach() { [native
>   code] }, get: function get() { [native code] }, has: function has() {
>   [native code] }, keys: function keys() { [native code] }, set:
>   function set() { [native code] }, values: function values() { [native
>   code] } }, json: function json() { [native code] }, ok: true,
>   redirected: false, status: 200, statusText: "", text: function text()
>   { [native code] }, type: "cors", url:
>   "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" }

Ahora por medio de la API Fetch pa procesamos de este modo mediante promises

```
fetch(url)
   .then(data => data.json())
   .then(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

**MANEJANDO LOS ERRORES AL MOMENTO DE HACER LA PETICIÓN**

Podemos recibir y reconocer los errores de la petición por medio de: `catch(error)`

```
fetch(url)
   .then(data => data.json())
   .then(data => console.log(data))
   .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

**MOSTRANDO EL ERROR EXACTO**

Si queremos mostrar el error exacto por el cual no se procesó la petición `GET` podemos añadir al `error` el acceso a `message` que contiene dicho mensaje

```
fetch(url)
   .then(d => data.json())
   .then(data => console.log(data))
   .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
```

Como notas he cambiado intencionalmente el nombre de `data` por d solo en una parte del código por lo cual el mensaje será el siguiente

> "data is not defined"

**PASANDO PARÁMETROS A LA PETICIÓN GET**

Pasar parámetros a nuestra petición  `GET` lo podemos hacer del modo siguiente

```
const datos = new URLSearchParams({
      id: 2
})
```

La *interfaz* `URLSerachParams` permite trabajar con parámetros pasados a URLs, se pasa un objeto donde la clave es el referente al nombre de la clave en el json que estamos obteniendo, el valor `2` es el valor dinámico que aplicaremos para filtrar de toda la data que solo nos muestre aquel registro que tenga el id 2

**COMPONIENDO A LA URL CON PARÁMETROS**

```
const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?${ datos.toString() }`
```

Hacemos uso de `toString` por que devuelve una cadena de texto que contiene el parámetro a consultar usado en una URL.

**USO DE ASYNC & AWAIT**

Con la implementación de estas 2 características entedemos que una función asíncroma que contiene un elemento precedido por `await` se va a pausar en su ejecución hasta obtener el resultado satisfactorio de la *promise*

El primer ejemplo del uso de *fetch* manejado mediante promises ahora luciría así

```
const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`

let fetchPosts = async() => {
  try{
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}

fetchPosts()
```

**ACLARACIONES**

- Los errores los manejamos a través de un bloque `try{....} catch(error){....}`
- Igualmente podemos acceder al mensaje de error al procesar la petición por medio de `error.message`

**PASANDO UN PARÁMETRO A UN CONSULTA**

```
const datos = new URLSearchParams({
      id: 2
})

const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?${ datos.toString() }`

let fetchPosts = async() => {
  try{
    const response = await (await fetch(url)).json()
    console.log(response)
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}

fetchPosts()
```