# Controlar flujo de funciones en AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

Tengo varias funciones AJAX y lo que quiero es tener una función que controle que cuando termine una, ejecute otra. Este es el esquema.

```
function ajax1(){}
function ajax2(){}
function ajax3(){}

//solo cuando termine ajax1 ejecutar ajax2 y así sucesivamente
function controladora1(){
    ajax1();
    ajax2();
    ajax3();
}

function controladora2(){
    ajax3();
    ajax2();
    ajax1();
}
```

Sé que se tiene que hacer con callbacks pero no me termino de aclarar.

Comment: Lo que hay que hacer es dar mas datos. Que son mas datos?
Saber si se repiten las mismas funciones o las funciones son dinámicas.
Eso de salida. Si son estáticas, en el ajax de la función ajax1, en el complete llamas a la función 2, y en el ajax2, en el complete de la llamada ajax, a la función 3

Comment: Relacionada: [¿Cómo realizar una llamada AJAX sin bibliotecas?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25798/127)

Comment: @Mikel Tienes razón quizás debería de haberme explicado un poco mejor, no me valen las funciones AJAX anidadas porque quiero tener el control de cada una independientemente. Fíjate que tengo _controladora1_ y _controladora2_ que ejecutan en orden distinto. 
Editaría la pregunta pero no se si es por novato o porque no me entero pero no veo donde está el botón de editar.

Comment: Si tienes alguna librería que use promises como jquery deberías usar esta y no callbacks. Estos son viables cuando no tienes lo anterior o no quieres usar una librería. De lo contrario terminaras con un [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya bien sabes, lo puedes controlar eso con `callbacks`, cuál lo pasas a cada función.

En el siguiente código el `setTimeout` es el simulador de ejecución de AJAX y/o cualquier tipo de código que necesite su tiempo:

```js
function ajax1(callback) {

    console.log('ajax 1');
    setTimeout(function(){ callback(); },1000);  
}

function ajax2(callback) {

    console.log('ajax 2');
    setTimeout(function(){ callback(); },1500);
}

function ajax3(callback) {

    console.log('ajax 3');  
    setTimeout(function(){ callback(); },2000);
}

function controladora1(callback) {
  
    ajax1(function() {
        ajax2(function() {
            ajax3(callback);
        });
    });
}

controladora1(function(){console.log('...y listo');});
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer pasando las funciones como parámetros de la función controladora y después ir pasando las funciones que necesites para la siguiente función también como parámetros:

```js
function controladora(ajax1, ajax2, ajax3) {
    //Aquí las funciones que necesites
    ajax1(ajax2, ajax3);
}

function ajax1(ajax2, ajax3) {
    alert("ajax1");
    ajax2(ajax3);
}

function ajax2(ajax3) {
    alert("ajax2");
    ajax3();
}

function ajax3() {
    alert("ajax3");
}
    
controladora(ajax1, ajax2, ajax3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias opciones, lo suyo, es usar `propromises`, pero puede llegar a ser un poco lioso.

Te dejo dos opciones, una con javascript puro (vanilla) y otra si piensas utilizar jQuery

> Vanilla js

```js
function xmlReq(url, retCallback, errCallback){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               //llamar a ajax 2
               retCallback();
           }
           else {
             errCallback(xmlhttp)
             }
        }
    };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

var url1 = "https://httpbin.org/get";
var url2 = "https://httpbin.org/get?x=v";
var url3 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

function llamar1() {
  console.log(" fin 1");
  xmlReq(url1, llamar2, errorHandler);
}
function llamar2() {
  console.log(" fin 2");
  xmlReq(url2, llamar3, errorHandler);
}
function llamar3(){
  xmlReq(url3, function() {console.log("fin 3")  }, errorHandler);
}
function errorHandler(xmlObj) {
  console.log("ha ocurrido un error " + xmlObj.status)
}

llamar1();
```

> jQuery

```js
var url1 = "https://httpbin.org/get";
var url2 = "https://httpbin.org/get?x=v";
var url3 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

$.ajax({url: url1, success: function(result){
  console.log("ok 1");
   $.ajax({url: url2, success: function(result){
        console.log("ok 2");
        $.ajax({url: url3, success: function(result){
          console.log("ok 3");
        
        }});
   }});        
}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿y este voto negativo? ¿Al menos el que lo haya votado negativamente podría dar una explicación? Creo que mi respuesta se ajusta a la pregunta.