# ¿Cómo obtener body desde url con JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

He buscado bastante y no he podido encontrar lo que necesitaba, así que decidí postear acá la duda. Si está repetido les pido disculpas.

La cuestión es que tengo una página `.php` que devuelve una respuesta, simplemente es una letra `C` (si es correcto) o `X` (si no está registrado). Toda esta parte ya está hecha, aclaro por las dudas. Lo que necesitaría hacer es capturar esa respuesta `(C o X)` con `Javascript`.

Ahora esa respuesta depende de un input `user` de `html`. El `url` de la página `.php` debería ser algo así `"http://xxx/app_user.php?pf=dame_resultado&p0="+user`, con el `input` `user` al final. Pero no sé cómo puedo hacer.

Les dejo  el código importante:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">

   <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>

       <input type="number" id="user" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresar Usuario" required>
   </div>

  <button id="btnIngresar" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="validar()">Ingresar</button>
</form>


function validar():
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    if (user != "") {
        alert(user);
}
```

Comment: Podría emplear `AJAX` _(Jquery quizá)_  para este fin , además se evitaría ese tipo de `URL's`  en el navegador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo con JavaScript , Podría emplear la  [API fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) para hacer la petición `GET` dentro de su función `validar`. *(Con respecto a las peticiones sin bibliotecas podría visitar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25798/c%C3%B3mo-realizar-una-llamada-ajax-sin-bibliotecas))*

```
function validar() {
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    if (user.trim().length < 1) //Validamos que no esté vacío el campo
        alert("Completar el campo Nombre");
    else{
        //creamos la url especifica con el valor de user concatenado.
        var url ="app_user.php?pf=dame_resultado&p0="+user;
        fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(function (body) { //Obtenemos el valor devuelto.
            alert(body);
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Con `Jquery` , se debería agregar el id `miform` al formulario.

```
$(document).on('submit','#miform',function(e){
    var nombre = $('#user').val();
    $.get( "app_user.php", { 
        pf:'dame_resultado',
        name: nombre 
    })
     .done(function( data ) {
        alert(data); // Obtener el valor.
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto. Sólo dos cosas, me devuelve el resultado en la alerta muchas veces. Y la otra, cómo sé qué tipo de variable es "data"?. Porque por ejemplo si quiero hacer un if (data=="C") no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Cuál de las dos opciones está empleando? , la variable data será de acuerdo a lo que retorne su archivo `PHP` _(no tengo referencia de esto en su pregunta)_, si solo retorna un texto como `echo "X"` , con la comparación `if(data==="X")` debería funcionar. si la respuesta es un array. tendría que acceder a su clave. `if(data.respuesta ==="X")`

Comment: La opción de Jquery, perdón me olvidé de aclarar.

Comment: @luis_snk no tengo referencia de su archivo PHP por lo cuál no sé como está retornando el valor , en mi comentario anterior especifiqué el tipo de respuesta posible. Por lo demás debería funcionar correctamente. Sí una respuesta soluciona su problema no dude en marcarla como aceptada. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

*Puedes buscar el query de la URL, asi:*

```
const url = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href); // Url actual 
const newURL = new URL(url); // Creo un objeto URL, pasandole la url actual

var getRegisterParameter = newURL.searchParams.get("registered"); // Obtengo el query llamado registered 


if(getRegisterParameter === "x") console.log("Succesfully..."); // SI EL QUERY ES IGUAL A X , ESTÁ REGISTRADO.
```

**Fuente:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams