# ¿Cómo capturar valor de atributo y pasarlo por Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estoy creando un foro. Este es el código HTML.En el atributo **data-id** con PHP imprimo el id de cada post:

```
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="jaja()" class="comentarPosts"  data-id=<?php echo 
      $posts_filas["Id_post"]; ?>><img src="img/message1.png"><span>25</span></a>
```

Tengo este código Ajax(JQuery),el cual quiero pasar a JS plano. Lo que busco es pasar el valor de **data-id**. Este código me funciona, pero quiero dejar de usar Jquery y usar JS plano.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on("click", ".comentarPosts", function () {

    var Id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#obtenerIdPost').val( Id );

 var datos = 'idPost='+ Id ;
 $.ajax({
 type:'POST',
 url:'comentarios.php',
 data:datos,
 success:function(result){
 $("#div1").html(result);
}
});
});
});
```

Este es el código Ajax con JS plano.

```
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("modal-message").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
};

 xhttp.open("POST", "comentarios.php", true);
 xhttp.send();

 }
```

Este es el código del archivo **comentario.php**:

```
<?php
 include('conexion.php');

 $id_post = $_POST['idPost'];

 $query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn, " 

SELECT 
   comentarios.id_usuario,
   comentarios.contenido,
   personas.nombre,
   personas.apellido,
   personas.Fotos 

 FROM personas 
 LEFT JOIN comentarios
  ON personas.Id = comentarios.id_usuario

 WHERE id_post = $id_post") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));



while ($posts_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_posts)) {


# code...
$Id = $posts_filas['id_usuario'];
$contenido2 = $posts_filas['contenido'];



if (mysqli_num_rows($query_buscar_posts) >0) { ?>

    <div class="wr_imnnacom">
    <div class="wr_img">
    <a href="#"><img style="width: 35px;height: 35px;" src='<?php echo 
     $posts_filas['Fotos']; ?>' ></a>
    </div>

<div class="wr_nm_comm">
    <div class="wr_comm_usrpc">
        <a href="user.php">
            <h5><?php echo $posts_filas['nombre'] . ' ' . 
 $posts_filas['apellido']; ?></h5>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="wr_comm_comm">
        <p class="aaaa"><?php echo $posts_filas['id_usuario'] . ' ' . 
  $posts_filas['contenido']; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="opt_this_comm">
    <a href="#">comentar</a>
</div>
</div>

<?php
    
}


else {
    
    echo "nada";
    
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el valor de un atributo usa `getAttribute()`

Para obtener un elemento por un atributo o por selectores de CSS, usa `querySelector()`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelector(".comentarPosts").addEventListener("click", () => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "comentatios.php"); // No utilices el tercer parámetro, está deprecado
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status <= 299 && xhr.status >= 200) {
                    document.getElementById("modal-message").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                } else {
                    alert("Error al conectar con la API");
                }
           }
        };
        const comentarPost = document.querySelector(".comentarPosts");
        xhr.send(`idPost=${comentarPost.getAttribute("data-id")}`);
    });
});
```

DOMContentLoaded detectará cuando el documento se ha cargado al completo, luego añadiermos un eventListener para detectar cuando se ha dado click a el botón con la clase *comentarPosts*, ten en cuenta que solo se aplicará el eventListener al primer elemento con esta clase; si necesitas añadir el eventListener a todos los elementos con esta clase usa `querySelectorAll()`, ten en cuenta que esto retorna un array, por lo que tendrás que hacer un forEach

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".comentarPosts").foEach(el => {
el.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "comentatios.php"); // No utilices el tercer parámetro, está deprecado
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status <= 299 && xhr.status >= 200) {
                    document.getElementById("modal-message").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                } else {
                    alert("Error al conectar con la API");
                }
           }
        };
        xhr.send(`idPost=${el.getAttribute("data-id")}`);
    });
});
});
```

### EDIT

Utiliza el siguiente código para enviar con POST

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelector(".comentarPosts").addEventListener("click", () => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "comentatios.php"); // No utilices el tercer parámetro, está deprecado
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status <= 299 && xhr.status >= 200) {
                    document.getElementById("modal-message").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                } else {
                    alert("Error al conectar con la API");
                }
           }
        };
        const comentarPost = document.querySelector(".comentarPosts");
        xhr.send(`idPost=${comentarPost.getAttribute("data-id")}`);
    });
});
```

El header "Content-type" nos permite enviar información con POST a través de nuestra petición.

### Edit 2

No encuentro problemas en la petición POST, puede que el problema esté del lado del backend. Prueba a esto en comentatios.php:

```
<?php
 include('conexion.php');

 $id_post = $_POST['idPost'];

 $query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn, " 

SELECT 
   comentarios.id_usuario,
   comentarios.contenido,
   personas.nombre,
   personas.apellido,
   personas.Fotos 

 FROM personas 
 LEFT JOIN comentarios
  ON personas.Id = comentarios.id_usuario

 WHERE id_post = $id_post") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));



while ($posts_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_posts)) {


# code...
$Id = $posts_filas['id_usuario'];
$contenido2 = $posts_filas['contenido'];



if (mysqli_num_rows($query_buscar_posts) >0) { 
foreach($query_buscar_posts as $any):
?>

    <div class="wr_imnnacom">
    <div class="wr_img">
    <a href="#"><img style="width: 35px;height: 35px;" src='<?php echo 
     $posts_filas['Fotos']; ?>' ></a>
    </div>

<div class="wr_nm_comm">
    <div class="wr_comm_usrpc">
        <a href="user.php">
            <h5><?php echo $posts_filas['nombre'] . ' ' . 
 $posts_filas['apellido']; ?></h5>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="wr_comm_comm">
        <p class="aaaa"><?php echo $posts_filas['id_usuario'] . ' ' . 
  $posts_filas['contenido']; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="opt_this_comm">
    <a href="#">comentar</a>
</div>
</div>

<?php
 endforeach   
}


else {
    
    echo "nada";
    
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Hay un error, seria `el.addEventListener`. A parte de eso, otra forma de leer `data attributes` es usar [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) y ya que estamos usando `ES6`, podría aprovechar y usar [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)

Comment: @Marcos no sabía de la existencia de dataset ¡gracias por tu aporte!

Comment: @Marcos Me lanza un error en la ventana modal y tiene que ver con "isPost". Voy a editar mi pregunta para añadir el código del archivo .php

Comment: @luis trata de usar el código que te puse en el edit.

Comment: @anythinggAcabo de probarlo. Te cuento que ahora si funciona, pero con el primer post. Me trae los comentarios de ese post, pero de los demás posts no me salen los comentarios.

Comment: @luis te aseguraste que tenga el encabezado `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`? Ten en cuenta que si no tiene este encabezado la información con POST no se envía.

Comment: @anythinggSi,solo copié tu código.

Comment: @anythinggPues me sigue igual, solo me salen los comentarios del primer post. Cuando quiero ver los comentarios del segundo, el tercer post,etc, el modal me sale vacío.

Comment: @luis has tratado de hacer un foreach en comentarios.php? En todo caso, te estoy dejando un edit, dame un rato para inspeccionar tu código y poder darte una solución adecuada.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117670/discussion-between-anythingg-and-luis).

Comment: @Marcos Y como traspasarías ese código a Fetch?

Comment: @luis, te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta, así la comunidad entera puede ayudarte a resolverlo. [Este articulo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25798/16597) puede que te sea de ayuda.