# ¿Como enviar una petición mediante AJAX y Json y recibir los datos del formulario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ya hice la llamada a la URL  y funciona, pero mi cuestion ahora es como puedo hacer una llamada AJAX, que me muestre solo los datos que añadido mediante un formulario con sus select y al darle a continuar

```
var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'https:mi URL';
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();

    Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
        console.log(Http.responseText)
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo realizar una llamada AJAX sin bibliotecas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25798)

Comment: Vale, voy a comprobar si es lo que necesito. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

creo que se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

1. definir un evento en el botón "continuar" para que se active cuando el usuario hace clic.
2. Luego, dentro de la función del evento, debes obtener los valores de los campos del formulario y enviarlos en una petición AJAX.

```
document.getElementById("botonContinuar").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'https://mi-url';
  var params = "campo1=" + document.getElementById("campo1").value + "&campo2=" + document.getElementById("campo2").value;

  Http.open("POST", url);
  Http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  Http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(Http.readyState == 4 && Http.status == 200) {
          //aquí es donde se mostrarán los datos de respuesta
          console.log(Http.responseText);
      }
  }
  Http.send(params);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es el envio de los datos ingresados en el formulario mediante AJAX aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append("{key1}", "{valor1}");
formdata.append("{key2}", "{valor3}");
formdata.append("{keyn}", "{valorn}");

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
//progressHandler funcion que se ejecutará mientras se envia el formulario
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
//progressHandler funcion que se ejecutará cuando se haya terminado de enviar
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
//progressHandler funcion que se ejecutará cuando se presente un error
ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", "{LA RUTA}");
ajax.send(formdata);
```

Esto lo metes dentro de una función que se ejecutará cuando lo veas por conveniente.